# U.S. rail terminal location county correspondence table

Tags: transportation, county, conversion

Does anyone know of a place to get a correspondence table between standard point location codes (SPLC) or freight station accounting codes (FSAC), and county-level federal information processing standards (FIPS) codes? Preferable formats would be a txt, csv, or xlsx file.